# Retag questions tagged "css" and "transition" to use "css-transitions"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I'm new to how meta works, so please delete if this isn't how things work.

I've been tidying up a load of tags and have found a few issues.

Lots of things are tagged [transition](/questions/tagged/transition) or [transform](/questions/tagged/transform). They

Ideally we could consolidate a few things here:

These mappings would be worth doing in my opinion.

Questions tagged:

- [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [transition](/questions/tagged/transition)
- [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [transition](/questions/tagged/transition)
- [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) and [transition](/questions/tagged/transition)

to [css-transitions](/questions/tagged/css-transitions)

---

Questions tagged:

- [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [transform](/questions/tagged/transform)
- [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [transform](/questions/tagged/transform)
- [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) and [transform](/questions/tagged/transform)

to [css-transforms](/questions/tagged/css-transforms)

---

Questions tagged:

- [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [animation](/questions/tagged/animation)
- [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [animation](/questions/tagged/animation)
- [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) and [animation](/questions/tagged/animation)

to [css-animations](/questions/tagged/css-animations)

---

Questions tagged:

- [css](/questions/tagged/css) and [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)
- [css3](/questions/tagged/css3) and [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)
- [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) and [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)

to [css-gradients](/questions/tagged/css-gradients)

---

Should [css-gradient](/questions/tagged/css-gradient) also be renamed [css-gradients](/questions/tagged/css-gradients) for consistency?

Also, the same for the plurals: [transitions](/questions/tagged/transitions), [transforms](/questions/tagged/transforms), [animations](/questions/tagged/animations) and [gradients](/questions/tagged/gradients).

This would tidy up somewhere around 1000 questions I reckon.

Comment: YES YES YES YES

Comment: Also got a chance to enjoy Sublime Text's multiple cursors and reformat the whole thing. BECAUSE I CAN! :)

Comment: Nice :) But you did miss the incomplete sentence that starts with "They"...

Answer (score 1):

As with most retag requests that involve a multitude of ambiguous tags used in combination, there isn't a feasible way to automate this.

Since this has bothered me as well for the *longest* time now, count me in!

If anyone else is helping out, some tips:

- Don't remove language tags unless they're absolutely not related to the question at hand. (Though personally, I'm going to try and not care whether a question is tagged [css](/questions/tagged/css), [css3](/questions/tagged/css3), or both, as I've always had... issues... with questions carrying only the latter tag and not the former.)
- If you're familiar with these CSS3 modules, take note that users who are unfamiliar with them may get the three terms (transitions, transforms and animations) mixed up. See if you can fix them!

Comment: Do you think we should keep the CSS, CSS3 and Webkit tags? I've been simply changing for instance, [tag:transition] to [tag:css-transitions], then leaving the other tags alone. I've already done about 20-50 of ones for the transitions by the way.

Comment: Not sure about the WebKit tag, but do keep at least one of the language tags on questions that involve CSS code. They are CSS questions after all.

Comment: Cool. That's what I thought.

Comment: Well, just got the Strunk and White badge!

Comment: Sweet. At this rate you'll earn Copy Editor soon enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+transition . No questions left! :) YAY!

Comment: Hopefully, we're not flooding the page too much. Take a break if you feel like it.

Comment: It's OK, I think I'm done. Only so much select `transition`, cmd-v I can take in one day! What tools are there available to you/SO admins regarding tags? Is it just rename and consolidate?

Comment: The devs can query the crap out of the database. Us mods only have merge and synonym tools, which don't exactly help here because the transition, transform and animation tags all have multiple meanings.

Comment: OK, that's what I assumed. I agree, a global find/replace wouldn't be great here, and as you said above, a lot of people use `animation` when they mean `transition`.